# Soap message envelope formatting

Tags: java, soap, soapexception

I'm using an Java HttpsURLConnection to send an Soap envelope message. See below my Soap envelope payload:

```
OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
      Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
      
      wout.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\r\n");  
      wout.write("<S:Envelope xmlns:S= ");
      wout.write(
        "'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>\r\n"
      );
      wout.write("<S:Body><ns2:getAccessibleDBs xmlns:ns2=");
      wout.write(
        "'http://webservice.namespace.com/'>\r\n"); 
      wout.write("  </ns2:getAccessibleDBs>\r\n");
       wout.write("  </S:Body>\r\n"); 
      wout.write("</S:Envelope>\r\n"); 
      
      wout.flush();
      wout.close();
```

However the server message is as follows:

> com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter                    E Unsupported Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Supported ones are: [text/xml]
> com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Supported ones are: [text/xml]

How can I format the message payload in order to avoid this error?

Comment: Why do not you use xsd for create soap message?

Comment: Hello Zeppee, du to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080615/url-with-https-protocol-in-soap-webservice-java-1-6

Answer (score 0):

You have two hardles,

1. You're not setting accurate HTTP Header `Content-Type="text/xml"` that server is expecting.
2. Your XML is incorrect. It should be like below, no unnecessary newlines `\r\n` etc and namespace should start with `double quote` rather then single quote.

   `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
   `<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`
   `<S:Body><ns2:getAccessibleDBs xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.namespace.com/">`
   `</ns2:getAccessibleDBs></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

It should work if you do above two changes.